# How to use third-party python plugins\extensions?

Tags: python, read-the-docs, mkdocs

I've read on the [docs](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builds.html#packages-installed-in-the-build-environment) that only few plugins are pre-installed in the virtualenv where the build happens. How can I use the read the docs service with custom plugins then?

I am using `mkdocs` to build a little documentation, in the `mkdocs.yml` configuration file I've added the following extensions:

```
markdown_extensions:
    - smarty

    - admonition

    #https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/abbreviations.html
    - abbr

    #https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/definition_lists.html
    - def_list

    #https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/footnotes.html
    - footnotes

    #https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/
    - pymdownx.emoji:
        emoji_generator: !!python/name:pymdownx.emoji.to_png

    - pymdownx.details
    - pymdownx.superfences
    - pymdownx.caret
    - pymdownx.mark
```

In the local environment the preview served with `mkdocs serve` is working fine, when deploying to read the docs (via a connected github repo) the build fails because it can't find the `pymdownx` plugins but I thought that they would have been automatically fetched by RTD apart from the default plugins present in the build env.

Comment: Not specific to RTD, but in case someone lands here with a different question, make sure to `pip install pymdown-extensions`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Read the Docs (RTD) does not support using third-party extensions. In fact, RTD only supports MkDocs version 0.14. However, MkDocs has had multiple additional releases since (currently up to 0.16), each of which has fixed multiple bugs and added various features.

RTD is unique among hosts for MkDocs. For all other hosts, you need to build the site locally before pushing to the host. This allows you to ensure you have an environment suited for your build. However, RTD builds the site on there servers, which means you are stuck with their environment, which may or may not fit your needs.